# Implement this mysql command in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

How to implement this `mysql` command in laravel eloquent ?

```
SELECT count(distinct(sender_id)) as responds FROM `messages` WHERE job_id=3
```

Comment: And what did you already try?

Comment: I want to know is there any way to implement "distinct" in Eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) thoroughly (RTM!), it's all there, optionally open up [API page](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/index.html).

You may try as:

```
Message::where('job_id','=',3)
        ->distinct()
        ->count();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects)

Answer (score 1):

try this Laravel query

```
$msg=DB::table('messages')
->distinct()
->count('sender_id')
->where('job_id','=',3)
->get();
```

Comment: I don't believe that `distinct()` takes arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an eloquent model, you would do something similar to the following:

```
$count = Message::where('job_id',3)->count('sender_id');
```

---

Or you can use the query builder. Maybe something like:

```
$count = DB::table('messages')->where('job_id',3)->count('sender_id');
```

or

```
$count = DB::table('messages')->where('job_id',3)->distinct()->count();
```

---

[Here is a link to the doc about Query Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects).

Answer (score 0):

Try Like:

```
 $model->where('job_id', '=', 3)->distinct()->count('sender_id');
```